# Cloudwatch set alarm if no message in sqs for an hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to alarm in cloudwatch when there is no message in SQS for a hour? I tried setting the following alarm:

```
Metric Name: NumberOfMessagesSent <= 0 for 60 datapoints within 1 hour
Statistic:SampleCount
Period:1 minute
```

However after 1 hour of no messages, it goes into the insufficient data alarm state. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SQS does not send metrics to Amazon CloudWatch **if the queue empty**.

Therefore, you should set your alarm to **trigger when the state is *INSUFFICIENT_DATA***. This will effectively be the same as testing for an empty queue.

[image: INSUFFICIENT_DATA]

Comment: Thanks. Is my setting of alarm to get into the insufficient state correct for my use case?

Comment: Test it and see!